# How to export a spreadsheet to PDF with columns populating the full page width

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, pdf-generation

Helllo everyone. I have created a macro to export some templates I've built in excel. The range of the templates are A1:T79. I set up the code below to take that range and turn it into a PDF document (which works fine).

The problem is that the pdf document it creates has a huge margin of space on the right hand side. I want the the columns (A through T) to FULLY populate the page width end to end (doesn't matter about how many pages that adjusts to in length).

I've tried a number of things and looked at some related links on this website but none have worked (which is why i'm asking again as opposed to responding to an old post over a year old!). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code is below. Let me know if I've not explained anything properly and I will respond below. Thanks! :)

```
Sub PDF_Gen()

'Set Page Area. My attempt at trying to fix the page width which doesn't work

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T79")
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .Zoom = False
End With

'Convert to PDF and save document in C drive

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\template1.pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I've tried some of the solutions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127693/all-columns-of-excelsheet-are-not-fitted-in-same-page-of-pdf-while-converting-u Although that was how to 'squeeze' a large number of columns into one PDF. I'm trying to do the opposite in making 20 columns fit neatly into one PDF document without any right or left margins...

Comment: Does your sheet look OK in Print Preview or have a wide right margin?

Comment: If I set the Workbook View to Page Break Preview mode and manually select the same range for page 1, there is still a small margin but it looks alot better in print preview. Unfortunately ive tried doing the same and then running the pdf generator (excluding the page set up step) but it still has the margin in the pdf document (which leads me to believe that its a problem with the pdf step as opposed to formatting in excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has fixed itself now bizarrely. I've just set the Page Break Preview range and it has worked this time, so i'm not going to ask any questions and just accept it! This is the code i'm going with

```
Sub PDF_Gen()

Dim Title As String

'Set Page Break Preview area

ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$T$79"

'Convert to PDF and save in C drive

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\template1.pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```