# The pagesetup for pdf printout in my vba code does not seem to work for me, any suggestions?

Tags: excel, vba

the code below seems to set the right print area, but when it exports to pdf, it still does not fit all the columns on one page. The end result I am looking for is to have all the columns fit on one page (landscape), but the rows do not have to fit on one page. [PDF1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSc9m.png) [PDF2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z93oS.png) [SampleXLSX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRkA2.png)

```
  For k = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
If wb.Sheets(k).Name Like "Facility List" Or _
   wb.Sheets(k).Name Like "TimestampExportReport" Then GoTo line3

    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    wb.Sheets(k).PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$H$" & wb.Sheets(k).Cells(wb.Sheets(k).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Application.PrintCommunication = False

With wb.Sheets(k).PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0)
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = ePaperSize
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""

End With
    wb.Sheets(k).ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=strPathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Debug.Print k, strPathFile

 line3:

    Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try changing `.FitToPagesTall = False` to `.FitToPagesTall = 1`?

Comment: @Zach E Yes, it is the same result

Comment: This code looks like you got it from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127693/all-columns-of-excelsheet-are-not-fitted-in-same-page-of-pdf-while-converting-u) so my only other suggestion is manually setting the print area within Excel.