# Excel code produces different results depending on if I step through code or just let it run

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation

I've got a block of code that is looping through all of the sheets (except the first) in my workbook and printing them to PDF fitting all columns & rows to just a single page.  This works if I step through the code with F8, but if I just let the code run it's like it ignores my With ActiveSheet.PageSetup section of code altogether and each of the PDFs outputs with two pages.

Below is the code that I'm using (taken and tweaked from the accepted answer on this question: [All columns of excelsheet are not fitted in same page of pdf; while converting using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127693/all-columns-of-excelsheet-are-not-fitted-in-same-page-of-pdf-while-converting-u?rq=1))

```
Dim ctr
ctr = 2
Do While (ctr <= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ctr).Select
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .Zoom = 100
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf", _
                                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=True
    ctr = ctr + 1
Loop
```

I would expect that whether I'm running the code with F5 or stepping through it with F8 it would behave the same way, but that doesn't seem to be the case here and I can't figure out why.

UPDATE: Rory answered question below, the second "Application.PrintCommunication = False" should have been "Application.PrintCommunication = True".

Comment: Remove the ```select``` and ```activesheets``` and put in explicit references, see if that fixes it. Also remove the ```on error resume next```, if theres an error you won't see it.

Comment: Change the second `Application.PrintCommunication = False` to `True`. If that doesn't help, remove them both.

Comment: Thanks @Rory that did it!  If you submit that as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

The link I copied from had that code, but I had accidentally deleted that line at one point and just re-typed it in rather than Undoing until I got it back (had made a few other changes before I noticed, didn't want to have to redo all of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second `Application.PrintCommunication = False` to `Application.PrintCommunication = True`